# Only 70Mh/s with good PC! AMD CPU not supported?

Tags: mining-profitability, hashpower, gpu-mining, cpu-mining

I have a AMD 8-Core-CPU with a NVIDA GTX 560 for Bitcoin-Mining but I only get 70Mh/s...

If I start CGMiner without GPU it detects nothing. Why cant I use my CPU to mine Bitcoins? Is that an error by the program? Which Software is the best to farm?

With best regards

Answer (score 0):

CPU and Nvidia GPUs are too slow for mining.

You may be able to make a profit for a while still with AMD graphics cards, if you have cheap or free electricity. But soon Bitcoin ASICs will take over completely. Then the only way to mine that makes sense is to buy specialized Bitcoin hardware.

Comment: +1 dr haribo, For my example I bought an NVidia card 1GB DDR3 card from Nvidia and saw a perfomrance along the lines of 8 MHash/S. When I swapped this out for an ATI card that was maybe 10 more expensive but with the same specs, I saw that my speed jumped up to 13.2 MHash/S

Comment: Seems odd that the NVidia card wouldn't be detected, though. OpenCL can definitely use NVidia cards.

Comment: The GPU is detected. He's asking why the CPU isn't "detected" in cgminer. The answer is that CPU mining no longer makes sense and therefore cgminer removed support for it.